# What does nonlocal coupling mean in the context of oscillators?

Tags: dynamical-systems, coupling

I am trying to understand some papers on chimera type behaviour but I don't understand what nonlocal coupling means in the context "... in nonlocal coupling oscillator system". This is the paper: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014JPSJ...83c4002L/abstract

Any explanations would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the rather detailed history in [Martens, Thutupalli, et al. (2013) *"Chimera states in mechanical oscillator networks"*](https://www.pnas.org/content/110/26/10563) the oscillators have a spatial arrangement. Local coupling would be interaction between close or direct neighbors, non-local coupling thus interaction with distant oscillators. Usually the non-local coupling is weaker than the local coupling, for instance falling with the distance.

The example first discussed is metronomes on horizontally moving platforms that are bound to some center location (here by being swings). Metronomes on the same platform are locally coupled. Connecting the platforms with (weak) springs then introduces non-local coupling.

Metronomes on a single isolated platform tend to synchronize, non-local coupling can destroy this synchronization among the metronomes on the same platform.