# How do you call this system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, physics, index-notation, biology

Is there a specific name for a dynamical system that depends on the relative indexation $i\pm k$ for some $k$? For example, consider the following dynamical system defined on a ring of cells by
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{u}_i&=u_i+2(v_{i-1}+v_{i+1})\\
\dot{v}_i&=u_i-v_i
\end{align}
$$
for each cell $i$, where the derivative is with respect to time $t$.

The main reason I ask this is because I won't to compare this kind of systems with systems involving spatial coordinates, $u(x,t)$, as in reaction-diffusion equations.

Comment: It's really just an ODE system, but since it is banded and "regular", you might expect that it has some spatial continuum limit. For example you might identify $v_{i-1}+v_{i+1} \sim 2v+h^2 v_{xx}$.

Comment: The real problem is that there's no reason to expect the $h^2 v_{xx}$ term to be significant, unless your boundary conditions cause it to be a singular perturbation.

Comment: @Ian I see, I guess ultimately this is but a discrete particular case of reaction-diffusion. I've been trying to understand better the Fourier transforms involved in the linear stability analysis of such systems. While much literature deals with reaction-diffusion, I haven't been able to find much examples on the index-based ODE systems such as this. Hence my interest.

Comment: While @Ian is correct that these are just an ODE system, they have their own methods. You can find some references to the literature and general discussion, along some examples, [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10958-005-0345-2.pdf), especially Section 1.4 and whole Chapter 4.

Comment: This is a system with near-neighbor interaction. There are some explorations of synchronization and chaos in such systems where interaction falls strongly with distance or is restricted to a finite neighborhood, such as putting closely tuned metronomes on movable platforms that are then weakly coupled, see for further keywords https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996849

Answer (score 1):

The ODE system is translationally invariant, if $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ or the indices have periodic boundary conditions (identifying $i=N+1$ with $i=1$), meaning that no unit $i$ is distinguished. Translation invariance implies that the system specified in  matrix form contains a (block) circulant matrix. In addition, the circulant is banded, as stated by Ian.

Comment: How do you see that it's circulant?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix In a circulant matrix, each row contains the same sequence of elements, shifted one unit relative to the previous row. Translational invariance (dependence of entries on differences of indices only) of the problem as stated thus directly makes the matrix a circulant.

Comment: Analogously, this also often transfers to continuous variables, where the RHS of the equation of motion for $u(x,t)$ depends on the differences of first variables only. It in particular applies if the time evolution operator is local, e.g. a differential operator, which depends only on the location $x$ itself.