# Equivalence of reaction-diffusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, physics, mathematical-physics

For $N$ cells in a one-dimensional ring, imagine a dynamical system given by, for each cell $1\leq i\leq N$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dx_i}{dt}&=f(x_i,y_{i-1},y_{i+1})\\
\frac{dy_i}{dt}&=g(x_i,y_{i})
\end{align}
$$
for any non-linear $f$ and $g$. A reaction-diffusion system (in 1 dimension) is of the form
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}&=K_u\partial_{xx}u(t,x)+F(u,v)\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}&=K_v\partial_{xx}v(t,x)+G(u,v)
\end{align}
$$
for constants $K_u,K_v$ and non-linear functions $F,G$.

Is it possible to write the first system as a reaction-diffusion system? I suspect it is since I can think of the first system as a discretization of the one-dimensional ring ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4343121/how-do-you-call-this-system)), but I am lacking the right notation. Any ideas?

Comment: Try writing $y_{i-1} = y_i + (y_{i-1} +y_i) $ and then assume $(y_{i-1} +y_i)$ is very small and expand $f$.

Comment: That is interesting, almost like a limit to reaction-diffusion. But how exactly to expand $f$?

Comment: Taylor series. Note that this is an [approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_size_expansion) .

Comment: My above comment had a typo, I mean $y_{i-1} = y_i + (y_{i-1} - y_i)$ etc, of course.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't get anywhere regarding the second spatial-derivative. Could you clarify the idea behind Taylor-expanding $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stay analogous to your example, lets rename the variables:

\begin{align}\frac{du_{i}}{dt} & =f(u_{i},v_{i-1},v_{i+1})\\
\frac{dv_{i}}{dt} & =g(u_{i},v_{i})
\end{align}

next, lets go to the continuum limit:

$u_{i}\rightarrow u(i\Delta x) $and similarly for $v_{i}$

so

\begin{align}
\frac{du(t,x)}{dt} & =f(u(t,x),v(t,x-\Delta),v(t,x+\Delta))\\
\frac{dv(t,x)}{dt} & =g(u(t,x),v(t,x))
\end{align}

now expand to second order in $\Delta$

\begin{align}
\frac{du(t,x)}{dt} & \approx f(u(t,x),v(t,x)-\Delta\partial_{x}v+\frac{1}{2}\Delta^{2}\partial_{x}^{2}v,v(t,x)+\Delta\partial_{x}v+\frac{1}{2}\Delta^{2}\partial_{x}^{2}v)\\
\frac{dv(t,x)}{dt} & =g(u(t,x),v(t,x))
\end{align}

A consistent expansion of $f$ will provide you with the reaction-diffusion form, possibly with a convection ($\partial_{x}$) term.